# Passing multiple view models in a single view

Tags: asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Even though that i believe that i have all the models defined and hopefully passed in properly but i am getting an error which states that i am passing in one model when it requires another model.

Main View:

```
@model Project.Models.ProfileModel

 @(ViewBag.HasLocalPassword ? Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial", Model.PasswordModel) : Html.Partial("_SetPasswordPartial", Model.PasswordModel))

            @Html.Partial("_UsernamePartial", Model.UsernameModel)
            @Html.Partial("_PlayNamePartial", Model.PlayNameModel)
```

Models:

```
 public class ProfileModel
{
    public PasswordModel PasswordModel { get; set; }
    public PlayNameModel PlayNameModel { get; set; }
    public UsernameModel UsernameModel { get; set; }
}
```

UserName Action GET:

```
public ActionResult _UsernamePartial()
    {
        var usernameModel = new UsernameModel();
        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            usernameModel.Username =
                (from u in db.Users where u.ID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId select u.Username).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return PartialView(usernameModel);
    }
```

UserName POST Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _UsernamePartial(UsernameModel usernameModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new DataContext())
            {
                User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                user.Username = usernameModel.Username;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View("_UsernamePartial");
    }
```

Profile Action:

```
public ActionResult Profile(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        var profile = New ProfileModel();
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : "";
        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Profile");
        return View(profile);


    }
```

View Page for UserName:

```
@model Acatar.Models.UsernameModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("_UsernamePartial", "Account")) {

       <p id="legend">Username</p>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Username)

    <button type="submit" value=" Username">Save</button>
}
```

**Error Message:** `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Project.Models.ProfileModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Project.Models.UsernameModel'.`

Would really appreciate any help of where i am going wrong.

Comment: to what view page do you actually sees that error?

Comment: @bot on the main view page - the first section of code i have. Am I supposed to be passing in all the GETS for the the three models into one GET method in the Profile page?

Comment: @BB987, no you do not have to post all Gets to same page. interestingly, you have a child method for _UsernamePartial that is never used. not related to your problem, but interesting

Comment: OIC, @BB987, you have unintentionally created child action methods. You name your action methods after your partials. Your intention was (by seeming convention) to post to them. But they in fact attempt to return the Partials.

Comment: @DaveA my overall problem for this is that before i had my page load fine with textbox but i wanted them to be prefilled with data that was saved previously and it wasn't doing that because it was getting a null reference so nothing was showing. But it was saving properly after checking changes in database.

Comment: @DaveA Also in my url if i go directly to _UsernamePartial view page - it works perfectly loading into the textbox but only when i want to have multiple views that will load data all into the same screen that it is not showing.

Comment: @BB987, the big question is: did you intend for your partials to be populated from the models you passed or from the child actions they share. If you intended to use child actions, the Paul Mendoza's method suits your needs best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call Html.Partial I don't believe that it invokes the action method. You should be using Html.RenderAction() which will invoke the controller action.

Comment: I don't think it was @BB987 intention to use his partials with Child Actions. I could be wrong, but I think his intention was to have the rendered forms post to Actions named after their corresponding Views. This would be a beginner's misunderstanding of convention. I think...

Comment: Ok so i get this right - i will use Html.RenderAction() in the Profile (main view)?

Comment: That won't solve all your problems. You should NOT post your form to _UsernamePartial unless it returns a usernameModel. That Method will be 'bound' to your partial and will try to render it. But your partial expects a model of type usernameModel.

Comment: @DaveA. WOW! I just commented out my post method and ran the page and now it is working as it should perfectly. But if the user makes a change to `username` and the save - don't i still need the POST in order to save to the database? or is this done differently

Comment: @BB987 yes you should post but to the parent Views methos, dont ever post to a method named after a partial unless you want to use that method to call the partial. read the link i included below my answer. it explains the association you accidentally made between your actions and partials. and it speaks to what Paul was telling you.

Comment: @DaveA Thanks a bunch you've been a great help and will go ahead read the link and will fix my post naming and hopefully i won't run into anymore problems tonight.

Comment: If you really want to implement something like what Paul Mendoza is suggesting you can do this in this way. @{Html.RenderAction("_UsernamePartial", "ControllerName"); }. Add this to your main view.

Comment: @bot yest that worked out but since the username textbox has a save button next to it - how will that trigger the Post because what you have works great for displaying the GET results

Answer (score 1):

When you post to `_UsernamePartial`, this acts as a child action method that returns another Partial. You are passing back

You are effectively passing back the View _UsernamePartial but returning it

```
return View("_UsernamePartial");
```

without the usernameModel

Comment: @BB987, read this post on partials and child actions, it should clarify a lot http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/